# SailsJS custom configuration file is not loaded

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I've been trying to load custom configuration for my application as explained in documentation and here on StackOverflow, but it fails.

I've created a new file in

> /config/application.js

With contents:

```
module.exports.application = {
  name: 'SuperApp'
};
```

Then in my

> /views/layout.ejs

I tried to read the property:

```
<title><%= sails.config.application.name %></title>
```

And it fails with error:

```
Cannot read property 'name' of undefined]
path: '/Users/glfx/Projects/superapp.dev/views/layout.ejs' }
```

Any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Have you restarted the application after you added the config file? This is loaded during boot and is not reloaded afterward (unlike your template).